# Can we write and run scripts in Selenium Webdriver without installing JDK?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. We are working on creating a POC for automation testing using Selenium. I wanted to know if we can write and run selenium webdriver test cases in Java without installing JDK? I do have JRE installed on my machine but in my project we cannot install JDK. Also, if we cannot, then what are the things we can and cannot perform if JDK is not installed?

Comment: to run java application you need only JRE, to develop java application you need JDK. JDK includes JRE.

Answer (score 2):

You only need of JRE.

See link:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing in Java you will need to have JDK installed. You cannot develop with JRE.

If you are doing this as only proof of concept you can explore other languages like Ruby, perl, python for quick development.